# What does "grade level" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following paragraph is from the [article](https://www.wsj.com/articles/illinois-shocking-report-card-reading-math-grade-level-decatur-teachers-school-board-11664722519?st=292nwcc17u7t5dq&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink) of the Wall Street Journal.

> Statewide, in 2019, 36% of all third grade students could read at grade level. That’s an F, and that’s the good news.

I am not sure the meaning of *at grade level* but I guess the level is what the educational authority thinks as proper. If so F which means *fail* seems to be acceptable. But why is it the good news? Is it because it dropped more later and just a sarcastic metaphor?

Comment: What is there to understand? "36% students could read at grade level" is definitely better than ":10% students could read at grade level" or "0% students could read at grade level".

Comment: "That's the good news" is a sarcastic joke. It's common to say things like "There is good news and bad news" ([New Yorker example](https://www.newyorker.com/humor/daily-shouts/bad-news-good-news)). This is funny in this case where the bad news is worse than the relatively poor "good news"

Comment: @Banuyayi - As a non-American, I wouldn't have known what _at grade level_ means.

Comment: In many non-UK English it is very common.

Comment: To help interpret "that's the good news", it might be useful to include the rest of the paragraph: "That number drops to 27% for Hispanic students and 22% for black students statewide. In certain public school systems, the numbers plummet to single digits. In Decatur, 2% of black third-graders are reading at grade level and only 1% are doing math at grade level." In other words, the overall 36% number is the (relatively) good news because there is also a lot of inequality and some groups are doing much worse.

Comment: Not again!  ***It's a typographical error***.  It should say "at third grade level"  Or perhaps "at their grade level".

Comment: Your separate unrelated question about "that's the good news" is simply answered by reading the next passage of the article.

Comment: I definitely disagree about it being a typo. As a native English speaker, i find "at grade level" a perfectly-acceptable phrasing of "at the level expected for their grade".

Comment: nah. That’s not a typo. “At grade level” meaning at the level expected of their grade. Shorthand, maybe. But repeating the level of the grade twice in the sentence would be redundant. I get it. Sounds natural to me.

Comment: @Fattie definitely *not* a typo.  The sentence explicitly refers to "third grade students" just before the "at grade level" clause.  **To Americans**, it's perfectly obvious that the grade level referred to is the one mentioned in the previous clause of the same sentence.

Comment: The F is not “acceptable”, it is simply superior (and in some cases vastly superior) to what the rest of the statistics show. I have no idea what the population breakdown is in that district, but unless there’s only 10 black 3rd graders AND there is some unknown but reasonable reason why 9 of them are having trouble with math, that 1% should result in everyone related to education be fired, possibly everyone in any local government position. Maybe they are all blind and deaf immigrants from a non-English speaking country, but otherwise that is so appalling that 36% does seem like good news.

Comment: @jmoreno It's more likely home/environment than the teachers.  Schools are to a large degree a reflection of the students rather than the cause.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: 1% needs more than a reflection of home life.

Comment: @jmoreno It's also the environment--when nobody cares about education there's no incentive for the kids to learn.  And when most of the students don't care there's not much the teacher can do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you consider that "grade level" means the reading level the student *should* be at for the grade that they are in (in this case, third grade), then 36% is very poor.

This isn't a case of a figure rising and improving from a low point; the benchmark is clearly set. The reading standard for a 3rd-grader should be achievable by *all* 3rd-graders, just as the standard for a 2nd-grader should be achievable all 2nd-graders, and so on. Of course there will be some outliers and I'm not qualified to say what a satisfactory percentage ought to be, but 36% is so low it is clearly a problem by any reckoning. Even 50% of something that *should* be 100% would seem problematic. If only 50% of brand new electrical appliances were in working order you'd think that was bad, right? They all *should* work and you'd expect a small percentage of slippage.

Regarding the use of "*that's an 'F'*" - I would describe that as a flippant, or irreverent remark. It isn't suggesting that this percentage of 36% actually equates to an 'F' grade on any scale; it is just using education terminology known to denote failure on a student level to humorously point out a failure in the entire education system. I wouldn't call this 'sarcastic' as such - sarcasm usually involves saying the opposite of what you believe, for example, saying "*that's just great*" about something that is clearly bad.

And 'that's the good news' isn't strictly sarcasm either, for the same reason - it may be said flippantly, but it isn't an example of saying something is good when it's bad - it is only *comparatively* good. I would guess that, in the wider context, the writer goes on to deliver *worse* news than this. It is playing on the common trope of '*I have some good news and some bad news*', only there's bad news and *worse* news.

Comment: @nanoman also, if we're going to be picky, the title of the question is "*What does "grade level" mean?*", which is the focus of my answer. The rules of the site say that a question should be focused. There shouldn't really have been so many unrelated questions posted as one.

Comment: And given the usual definition of 90-100% = A, 80-90% = B, 70-80% = C, 60-70% = D, anything lower than that being an F, 36% is not just an F, but a very low one at that,  Even if you scaled everything up such that 60% was a perfect score, 36% would still be 1% above an F.  It's basically an F of an F...

Answer (score 15):

As [Astralbee](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/324478/15847) said, "at grade level" here means "the reading level the student *should* be at for the grade that they are in". And, yes, 36% is very poor.

I'm going to focus more on the "that's the good news" part. The phrase "(and) that's the good news" is probably a fixed phrase at this point. It means something like "as bad as that last bit is, it gets worse"; I don't think it's a sarcastic metaphor so much as gallows humor. The article demonstrates this with the next sentences:

> That number drops to 27% for Hispanic students and 22% for black students statewide. In certain public school systems, the numbers plummet to single digits. In Decatur, 2% of black third-graders are reading at grade level and only 1% are doing math at grade level.

---

NB. [Gallows Humor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallows%20humor) from Mirriam-Webster:

> humor that makes fun of a life-threatening, disastrous, or terrifying situation

or, from [Google/Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=gallows%20humor):

> grim and ironic humor in a desperate or hopeless situation

---

So, the sentence is saying that only about 1 in 3 third graders have the reading - and reading comprehension - skills we as a society expect of 3rd graders *and* that, as bad as that number is, there's worse information to come.

Comment: I really wouldn't call this gallows humor. There's nothing life-threatening or terrifying here, in an immediate sense. Students who make jokes to cope with frequent school shootings may be engaging in gallows humor, but the danger from poor reading scores is much more indirect. But your summary in the last paragraph is exactly right.

Comment: +1 that "and that's the good news" is the real source of the confusion.

Answer (score 9):

## What is “third grade”?

In the US, an “*n*th grade” student is a member of a “class” of students that is *n* years into their required formal education.  The student's “grade level” increments at the start of a new academic year (which typically starts in August or early September, and ends in late May), unless they are made to repeat a grade due to low academic performance, or promoted multiple grades due to high academic performance.

Typically, there are 13 grades, with kindergarten (begun at age 5) effectively serving as a “0th grade”, then “1st grade” thru “12th grade”.  These are usually grouped into three stages, held at different school campuses:

- Kindergarten through 5th grade = “elementary school” (or more rarely, “primary school”)
- 6th through 8th grade = variously called “middle school”, “junior high”, or “intermediate school”
- 9th through 12th grade = “high school”

However, since the US doesn't have one unified education system, but a patchwork of states, counties, and school district, different places may have slightly different classifications.

Point is, “third grade students” are usually 8-9 years old.

## What does “at grade level” mean?

Various state education agencies have specific standards for what knowledge a student *should* have at each grade level.  For example, the math standards may say that second-graders should be able to evaluate multi-digit sums like 867 + 309, and that fifth-graders should know how to do long division.  English literacy standards will expect students to know the meaning and spelling of particular vocabulary words, and be able to handle a certain amount of grammatical complexity.

[Standardized tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_test) are often employed to evaluate whether students have, in fact, met their expected skill academic skill requirements.  This became especially more common after the passage of the [No Child Left Behind Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Child_Left_Behind_Act) in 2001.

If a student can “read at grade level”, it means that they're capable of reading material that the relevant educational standards organization expects them to be able to read.

## What is “an F”?

It's part of the traditional [grading system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_the_United_States) where a student is assigned a letter grade of `A` (the best), `B`, `C`, `D`, or `F` (failing), either on a particular assignment or exam, or for a course as a whole for an academic term.  Sometimes, these grades have `+` or `-` modifiers, such that `A+` > `A` > `A-` > `B+` > `B` > `B-`, etc.

“That's an F” is just using this educational terminology to say “That's unacceptable.”

## What is “the good news”?

It's a common idiom to say “I have good news and bad news” when delivering two related pieces of information.  A straight example is “The bad news is that our team lost our big rivalry game.  The good news is that we're still eligible for the playoffs.”

In the context of the article:

- “The good news” is that 36% of all Illinois third-graders could read at grade level, according to some (unstated) standardized test or study being cited.
- “The bad news” is that some subsets of these students are doing even worse, in particular *Black* third-graders in Decatur.  (It's very common in the US for Black people to fare poorly in social statistics compared to their White, Asian, or Latino counterparts.  The *reasons* for this are...controversial, to put it mildly.)

There's probably some sarcasm in the author's use of “and that's the good news”, because nobody would consider this poor outcome “good news” at all; it's only “good” *by comparison* to the *worse* news immediately after it.